# Probability of the k'th draw is the first time to draw correctly one of balls which were drawn previously

Tags: probability

> A box with $N$ balls. You draw balls sequentially one at a time and
> return it to the box. For each $k$, find the probability of the $k$'th
> draw is the firt time to draw correctly one of balls which were drawn.

I have two directions that give two different results. The first line of thought (based on solution in a material) is $\frac{k-1}{N}$, with the explanation being the probability of the $k$'th draw is the first time drawing exactly one of the balls previously drawn is equivalent to the probability of the $k$th draw that we draw exactly one of the already selected balls while $k-1$ previous times we draw completely different balls.

But I don't think that it is the true result. In my opinion, The condition for the $k$'th draw  satisfying the above requirement depends on whether $k-1$ times before we draw the previously drawn ball or not. So the result should be equal $\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n}\dots\frac{n-k+1}{n}\frac{k-1}{n}$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlainRemillard I have two directions that give two different results. The first line of thought (based on solution in a material) is $\frac{k-1}{N}$, with the explanation being the probability of the $k$'th draw is the first time drawing exactly one of the balls previously drawn is equivalent to the probability of the $k$th draw that we draw exactly one of the already selected balls while $k-1$ previous times we draw completely different balls

Comment: Could you edit your post to include this?

Comment: @AlainRemillard OK.